# How to write a test case for method which creates the table and add values

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm setting up java project where user enter his details and the data will be saved in the the database bellow is my code:

```html
public String CreateUserDetails() throws SQLException, JsonProcessingException 
 {
  iterationResourse = new IterationResourse();
  dbcon = DatabaseConnection.getInstance();
  iteratinDetails = IterationDetailsParser.getInstance();

  try {

   String sqlUser = "INSERT INTO user (User_Id,Username,Active_Indi)VALUES(?,?,?)";

   PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) dbcon.con.prepareStatement(sqlUser);
   statement.setString(1, iterationResourse.ConvertObjectToString(iteratinDetails.getUserId()));
   statement.setString(2, iterationResourse.ConvertObjectToString(iteratinDetails.getUserObj()));
   statement.setBoolean(3, true );
   
   statement.executeUpdate();
   statement.close();
   System.out.println("user created");
   st = "user created";
  } catch (SQLException e) 
  {
   System.out.println("user id alredy exits");
   userIdExits = false;
   ObjectMapper mapperUser = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode rootNode = mapperUser.createObjectNode();

   ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("Response", "User ID alreday exits");

   String jsonString = mapperUser.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
   System.out.println(jsonString);

   iterationResourse.response = jsonString;
   st = "Response\", \"User ID alreday exits";
  }
  
  return st;
 }
```

I have to write a test case for the above code i have tried the fallowing code. i am trying to mock all the objects that i am trying to use form the other class , the expected result should be string that returns "User created" . but i am unable the get the expected result based on the current code.

```html
public class UserDatabaseTest {


 
 User user = null;
 IterationResourse iterationResourse;
 DatabaseConnection db;
 IterationDetailsParser iterationDetails ;
 
 @Before
 public void setUp()
 {
   iterationResourse = mock(IterationResourse.class);
   db = mock(DatabaseConnection.class);
   iterationDetails = mock(IterationDetailsParser.class);
  user = new User();
  
 }
 
 @Test
 public void test() throws JsonProcessingException, SQLException {
  Object Object = "3";
  String value = "3";
  when(db.getInstance().GetDBConnection()).thenReturn(db.getInstance().GetDBConnection());
    when(iterationDetails.getUserId()).thenReturn(Object);
    
    when(iterationResourse.ConvertObjectToString(Object)).thenReturn(value);
  
  assertEquals(user.CreateUserDetails(), "user created");
 }

}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Don't try to mock low-lever classes like connections and statements. Put the DB access code in a separate DAO class, containing an insertUser() method, and mock that method. Also respect the Java naming conventions, and use a local variable for `st`rather than a field. It's also unclear why you log structured JSON to System out, and return strings from the method instead of doing the reverse.

Comment: okay i will update my code . Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to be written here.

1. CreateUserDetails return "user created"
2. Else return "User ID already exists" (i fixed the two typos)

As stated in the comments you should really abstract your DAO layer. But at a high level, you want to mock the DatabaseConnection and return mocks for anything it may return. Doing this prevents NPE's when calling your code base.

Once your mocks are in place the test should return "user created". For the second test have one of your mock throw an SQLException and you can test that "User ID already exists" is returned. I would probably just pass `iteratinDetails` as a parameter, seems like a dependency for this method.

Lastly, you should not be testing that your code has created database tables and populated them correctly. As long as the data you are passing in (which is something you can test) you should have faith that SQL is going to execute scripts as intended. If you really wanted to get crazy, you could do some mocking to ensure that the `statement` was prepared properly. IMO that's overkill.

Goodluck!